# Visual Studio 2022 is showing a lot of typescript errors. This are not appearing on vscode or when i compile my project via command linne

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, visual-studio-2022

app facebook template and added it to my project everything works correct but visual studio is showing weird errors I don't know why do you have any suggestions how to solve this ?

[image: typescript errors]

Comment: Any workaround? Please.